# Hololens store submission input not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-store, hololens

Building from VS to device works just fine. But building with Master settings and then it won't do. Since master is required for store submission then, downloading from store is getting the problem.

I have been trying to track the issue, and basically the input is just not working. If I perform a tap I get :

```
The thread 0x12a4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I think spatial mapping also gets a weird treatment which got me thinking it may be related to multithread (since the only correlation I can think of is the usage of multi-threading internally).

I thought it was only with one of our app first but then got told a second app totally different is also getting the same problem.

Anyone knowing what to do? 
I posted on hololens forum about 3 weeks ago but no one has yet replied.
Contacting Microsoft is a basic waste of time as I will probably never get anyone with that kind of knowledge.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue seems to come from the multiple .rcs files I was keeping. Only holding to the latest one seems to allow Master build to work.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem a long time ago, tbh I think this has something to do with the OS.

I started in a Win 10 Home pc, and I was getting the error.  When I switched to another PC with Win 10 Enterprise, it was working fine.  So I have been sticking with the Win 10 Enterprise pc ever since.

Comment: Actuallyy, not for me since I got it to work on the same PC by removing all the old rcs files. Though it works once out of few builds.